# Is it possible to autogenerate insert on foreign keys

Tags: mysql, database

Good day everyone, i have a question regarding on foreign keys, like is it possible to auto insert on foreign key when i insert data from the main table for example

Student_table

```
|Id  | Fname |LName|

|12  | John |Doe  |
```

Quizes_table

```
ControlNum(auto_increment)|Quiz1|Quiz2|Quiz|Stud_id(fKey)

1         |0              |0    |0    |0   |12
```

My simple solution was just make 2 insert query insert on students table and quizes table..but using this method im having a hard time when it comes to large amount of data and one to many relationships tables..

so my main question was can i make only one insert query on student table and the foreign key will generates depends on the your insert like for example

insert id on student table like id=14 Fname="myname", Lname = "mylastname" and the quizes table generate stud_id =14 and make the rest field to null or zero if its not possible then i have no other choice but to make each insert query but its kinda hassle for me on the actual real large datas (T_T)

Comment: You can do it with a trigger, but it's usually not a good practice to create irrelevant data in the database. The simple fact that the data doesn't exist should be enough for your program to initialize a new Quizz.

Comment: what do you mean insert.. a new record from main table or an old record from main table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can create a trigger for your student table:

```
CREATE TRIGGER student_ins AFTER INSERT ON student 
  INSERT INTO quizes SET stud_id = NEW.id;
```

Assuming you have sensible zero values as defaults for the other columns of your quizes table, or else let them be NULL.

I'm not sure how this accomplishes anything, though, since you would need to run another UPDATE query anyway, to populate the quiz scores later.

Comment: thanks this one works for me fine now dont have to worry on my actual project which has many sub tables that are connected to my main table thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

If you inserting a `new record` from main table into your foreign key table

You need to use [trigger After Insert](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/triggers/after_insert.php)

**Otherwise**
 you need to construct a `normal script` to insert a record to your foreign key table